# Performing unsupervised classification using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sentinel-2, normalized-difference-water-index

How to distinguish between water bodies and clouds using unsupervised classification in sentinel 2?

When i used NDWI and NDSI both are same objects.